# How to programmatically load an annotationlayer to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, annotation

I have a geodatabase with an annotation feature class in it containing 3 subtypes. Now I load the featuredataset to the map with this code:

```
IFeatureClass featClass = (workspace as IFeatureWorkspace).OpenFeatureClass(sNameOfFeatclass);
IFeatureLayer fLyr = new FeatureLayer();
fLyr.FeatureClass = featClass;
```

In ArcMap the opened Layer is displayed but symbology is like polygon classified with the subtypes. In debug mode I see that the featureclass is of type *esriFTAnnotation* and the subtypes are present but the layer does not support the interface *IAnnotationLayer*.

In resources I only have found how to create an AnnotationFeature Class, but in my case the featureclass exists. How can I load it to map so that in layer properties the tab *Annotation* is displayed and not *Labeling*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that annotation feature classes have two geometries: Shape and Element.. the Shape is the polygon, which you get if you open as an [IFeatureLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004tp000000), but to access the Element as text you need to open as an [IAnnotationLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00120000020q000000) using [IAnnotationLayerFactory.OpenAnnotationLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OpenAnnotationLayer_Method/00120000020v000000/):

```
IAnnotationLayerFactory pAnnoFact = new FDOGraphicsLayerFactoryClass();
IAnnotationLayer fLyr = pAnnoFact.OpenAnnotationLayer(
    (workspace as IFeatureWorkspace), 
    null, 
    sNameOfFeatclass);
    // parameter Feature Dataset is null because it's not in one.
```

then add the layer to your map like:

```
ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.AddLayer(fLyr as ILayer);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't know why i din't found the command. So it works:  `if (featClass.FeatureType == esriFeatureType.esriFTAnnotation)
                    {
                        IAnnotationLayerFactory pAnnoFact = new FDOGraphicsLayerFactoryClass();
                        IAnnotationLayer aLyr = pAnnoFact .OpenAnnotationLayer(workspace as IFeatureWorkspace, featClass.FeatureDataset, sNameOfFeatclass);  }`